# Clarification required for the 'Disable foreign key checks' option

Tags: mysql, import, foreign-keys

I'm looking for some clarification on a statement from the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks)

I intend to export a DB with the `Disable foreign key checks` option selected, as doing it without causes an error when I import the DB. However, after reading the docs I'm left with two questions with regard to importing the DB -

1. Will `foreign_key_checks` be set back to `1` automatically after the import for that DB, or do I have to do it manually?
2. will the Foreign Keys already in place when the DB was exported still be valid?

The relevant part of the docs reads as below, which to me is not particularly clear -

> Setting `foreign_key_checks` to `1` does not trigger a scan of the existing table data. Therefore, rows added to the table while `foreign_key_checks = 0` will not be verified for consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html

1. See the big table at the start. `foreign_key_checks` setting is session based. You do not have to reset it back to 1 yourself. (Although it doesn't hurt.)
2. Yes. No actual relations or constraints will be affected. Only the checking of those constraints during the time when the checks are off.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that would be the case, but I'd rather be sure than muck a load of stuff up!